Cognito Authorizing API in an app from a different app
I have three apps configured on AWS Cognito, and they use the same user pool and it works just fine.
But I am trying to make one of my apps hit the API in the different app, I built the access token like that in the calling app
var cognito = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var secretHash = CreateSecretHash(username,
    clientId,
    clientSecret);
var request = new InitiateAuthRequest
{
    ClientId = {clientId},
    AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    AuthParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "USERNAME", sameUsername },
        { "PASSWORD", Password },
        { "SECRET_HASH" , secretHash}
    }
};
var response = cognito.InitiateAuth(request);
return response.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;

Then I took that access token and hit my end point
  var c = new HttpClient();
  c.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
  var response =c.GetAsync(address).Result; 

Just ignore the Result thing, I am just testing, but the return value is the html of the login page, which means no authorization is happening.
I see that the app, that hosts the API, is telling me that the OpenIdConnect was challenged, but it never authorizes it.
I also tried to allow the request from the other app by adding this in the startup of the app that hosts the API
services.AddCors(item =>
{
    item.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44373/", "http://localhost:57019/")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

I do not know where I am going wrong, it is my first time dealing with AWS Cognito. Would somebody please help?
